# How to add android SDK to eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to re-compile android app from sources using Eclipse STS. I added the sources to plain new project. I ended up with missing dependencies for classes from `android.*` package.

To solve this, I decided to locate android SDK on my disk drive and use the Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Link source. There I selected path to the android SDK.

But this would produce lots of build errors for missing types, such as

> The import android.databinding.testapp.databinding cannot be resolved

I think what I did is not the correct way to include the SDK anyway.

What **is** the correct way to compile your Java code that uses Android SDK?

Comment: Android SDK with eclipse is no longer supported. Use Android Studio instead.

Comment: Do you "have to"  use eclipse?
Use Android Studio. More easy to use, comes with the sdk

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to continue to use Eclipse/STS for Android development, you could give Andmore a try: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore

Answer (score -1):

Try to download it from kickass torrent. After that go to your project -> right button -> properties -> android, and select the path where you have saved the android sdk.

Comment: Very bad advise and does not answers the question in any way.